# Angular JS Data filtering using checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular JS to filter data in a table (using arrays). There are two arrays originalData and filteredData, both initialized to the same thing. The checkboxes in the UI are initialized to true (therefore all the data is displayed for the table). When I click the checkbox to uncheck it, the data is removed accordingly so that part works. I re-click the check box to check it and it does insert the data back, but it takes the default original data value and the table is full of duplicates (originalData + duplicated data from checked box). My question is why is the filtered data not being stored?

```
//using ng-change in Angular for checkboxes (changeData function)

var originalData = miss_info;
var filteredData = miss_info;

$scope.changeData = function(requester){
    var t_requester = requester.ticketRequester;



    if(requester.status){
        //inserted filteredData back
        for(var i in originalData){
                if(t_requester == originalData[i].Requester){
                        filteredData.unshift(originalData[i]);
                }
                }
            }
    else{
        //remove from filtered data
        for(var i in filteredData){
                if(t_requester == filteredData[i].Requester){
                        filteredData.splice(i,1);           
                }
        }
    }   

    console.log(filteredData);      
    $scope.missInfo = filteredData;
};
```

The table is watching the variable missInfo for changes and updates accordingly.

Checkbox logic below:

```
   $scope.requesterTemps=[
              {'name': "BlahA",
               'ticketRequester': 'a',
               'status': true
               },
              {'name': "blahB",
               'ticketRequester':'b',
               'status': true
               },
              {'name': "blahc",
               'ticketRequester': 'c',
               'status': true
               },
              {'name': "blahd",
               'ticketRequester': 'd',
               'status': true
               },
              {'name': "blahe",
               'ticketRequester': 'e',
               'status': true
               },
              {'name': "Other",
               'ticketRequester':'other',
               'status': true
               }
             ];
```

Here is the html (table not shown):

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label ng-repeat="requester in requesterTemps">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="requester.status" ng-change="changeData(requester)"/>{{requester.name}}
  </label>
</div>
<table st-table="displayed" st-safe-src="missInfo" class="table table-striped"></table>
```

Comment: It's hard to tell looking at the code you provided. Can you crate a plunk out of it?

Comment: okay I'll add more of the code for the UI

Comment: Is it logging it correctly?

Comment: It works on the first check (filters the data in the table). The primary issue is that onChange, it re-initializes the filteredData (from the beginning) after I try checking/unchecking other checkboxes

Comment: ng-repeat keeps track of html elements with internal-id. try to set the id manually with this: `ng-repeat="requester in requesterTemps track by requester.name"`